# ITimerHandler is reducing by 2 instead of by 1 when 1 second past in AndEngine GLES2

Tags: java, andengine

i wanted to make a countdown in andengine, with a 1 second interval and for some reason instead of reducing by 1 after 1 second, is reducing by 2. This is my code:

```
    private void createTimeHandler() {              
         engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1, new ITimerCallback(){                      
                @Override
                public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                    pTimerHandler.setAutoReset(true);
                    System.out.println("Seconds Elapsed: " + pTimerHandler.getTimerSecondsElapsed());
                    System.out.println("Seconds: " + pTimerHandler.getTimerSeconds());
//                  if(pTimerHandler.getTimerSeconds() == 1.0f) { 
                        System.out.println(ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime);
                        ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime -= pTimerHandler.getTimerSeconds();
                        timeTitleValue.setText("" + ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime);
//                      
//                  }
//                  pTimerHandler.reset();
                    if (ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime == 0) {
                            //End screen
                    }
                    if (ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime <= 10) {
                            //timerTickSound.play();
                    }
                    if (ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime > 0) {

//                          
                    }

                }
       }));
    }
```

Tried with many other ways to do it, in all the ways, it takes 2 instead of 1 per second! im really desperate, been fighting with this thing for hours :S

Even tried with this class that someone from here created

http://pastebin.com/Rf8DWGv4

And this is how it looked in my code:

```
private void createTimeHandler() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1.5f, new Timer.ITimerCallback() {
        public void onTick() {
            String timeNow = String.valueOf(ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime -= 1);
            timeTitleValue.setText(timeNow);
        }
    });
    engine.registerUpdateHandler(timer);
}
```

Adding the createTimeHandler() inside of the createScene method under GameScene.

Can anyone help me ??

Thanks!

Comment: Does andengine really have no documentation to speak of?

Comment: No, anything about it :S

Comment: Guess you have to read the source yourself.

Comment: made it work. The error was in the registering event to the engine instead of the Scene :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. Instead of registering the event to the engine, i had to register the event to the gameScene.

So the code would be like:

```
private void createTimeHandler() {              
         gameScene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1, new ITimerCallback(){                      
                @Override
                public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                    pTimerHandler.setAutoReset(true);
                    System.out.println("Seconds Elapsed: " + pTimerHandler.getTimerSecondsElapsed());
                    System.out.println("Seconds: " + pTimerHandler.getTimerSeconds());
//                  if(pTimerHandler.getTimerSeconds() == 1.0f) { 
                        System.out.println(ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime);
                        ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime -= pTimerHandler.getTimerSeconds();
                        timeTitleValue.setText("" + ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime);
//                      
//                  }
//                  pTimerHandler.reset();
                    if (ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime == 0) {
                            //End screen
                    }
                    if (ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime <= 10) {
                            //timerTickSound.play();
                    }
                    if (ResourcesManager.getInstance().levelTime > 0) {

//                          
                    }

                }
       }));
    }
```